# Add the field "Subject" to moderncv letter

Tags: macros, moderncv, letterhead

As discussed on this forum [latex-community: How to include Subject to letter](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=26922), I'd like to add an extra field "Subject: " to moderncv letter template.

```
\bigskip
\textbf{Subject: \@subject}
\bigskip\noindent
```

the new `\makeletterhead` command will be something like this:

```
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender block
  \makehead%
  \par%
   % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
%_______________________
\bigskip
\textbf{Subject: \@subject}
\bigskip\noindent
%_______________________
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
```

Not to forget that the parameter `\@subject` should be retrieved somewhere.

**EDIT**

The question is how to add a "Subject" field in a way that when the command `\makelettertitle` is executed the subject text will be placed before the openning statement.

Comment: it would be better to provide a usable example, but also what is your question? The code looks more like an answer than a question. (although you should not have `\noindent` after the `\bigskip`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes but not a correct answer i got some errors (not related to the fact `\@subject` is not defined yet) when copy pasting this code to override `makeletterhead` definition. `You can't use `\spacefactor' in internal vertical mode. There's no line here to end....`

Comment: but that's just the standard "use `\makeatletter` or put the code in a package" that applies to any  command with `@` in its name, unrelated to moderncv.  you just want `\newcommand\subject[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}` to be defined somewhere that `@` is a letter or don't use `@` use `\Xsubject` or any other internal name that is a valid command name.

Comment: but anyway if you are asking about an error message the example code should be a complete document that generates the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks another silly mistake from me, indeed it was because the lack of`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:) `\newcommand\subject[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}` was helpful as well you can post an answer or i will.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328056/add-the-field-subject-to-moderncv-letter#comment803169_328056) I have corrected my attempt, here's an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\nopagenumbers{}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{20}{29}\mdseries\upshape}

\firstname{LaTeX}
\familyname{MiKTeX}
\address{Tex.Stackexchange.com}{0000}
\phone[mobile]{00~00~00~00~00}
\email{project-admin@latex-project.org}

%%%%
%Add the field "Subject" to the definition of the letter header
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subject[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  \makehead%
  \par%

  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  %________ADDED_<<<<<<
\bigskip
\textbf{Subject: \@subject}\\
\noindent
%_______________________
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother
%%%

\begin{document}
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\Some City 00000}
\date{Septembre 05, 2016}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\subject{Apply for...}

\makelettertitle

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

The definition of the command `\makeletterhead` was picked from [moderncvbodyiii.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadiii.sty) since the `banking` style (used in the example) uses `moderncvbodyiii.sty` file.