# Adding title and alignment of adress, moderncv

Tags: align, titles, moderncv, cv

I am modifying my cover letter with `moderncv`. In particular, I want to add  a title line, justifying the body text and align both adresses on the same height (companies adress top left, my adress top right). I found a couple of posts to the regarding Topics and I add the code parts into my TeX file. They are all working singular, but not in combination and I can't figure out why. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm} 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}                             
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}                   
\email{Mail}  

%Justification    
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
   {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother        




 %Adds title                                         
   \makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}{%search
          \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
        }{%replace
          \raggedright%
  \textbf{\@title}\\[1.5em]
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
        }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother       


 %Should align both adresses on the same "height"
 \makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
    % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth} % <================================
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}% <=================================
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details%
      \raggedleft%
      \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
        {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
        % optional detailed information
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}\fi%
      \\[1em] % <=======================================================
      \@date % <========================================================
    \end{minipage}\\[2em] 
  % opening
% \raggedright% <=======================================================
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}
\subsection*{FooFoo}

\clearpage

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\title{Heading should look like this} % <===============================
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus 
et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna 
libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, 
tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci 
lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam 
venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]


\end{document}
```

The cover letter is justified and the adresses are on the same height, but the title is not involved. Maybe someone knows how to solve that problem. I am not so advanced to understand the changes in the `\patchcmd` arguments, Maybe there is the problem.

[image]

I already tried the regarding code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328056/add-the-field-subject-to-moderncv-letter), but it doesnt work in combination with the justificatoin and the alignment of the adress

Comment: already tried inside my code and it doesnt work

Comment: Can you add what you tried to incorporate the solution from the "duplicate question" into your code?

Comment: @Vala: Are you just interested in a cover letter, or do you have the entire thing done in [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) because your attached CV? If you don't have a CV attached to it, you can just recreate a cover letter using the regular `article` document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest way is to move the function of the two `\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}`s into your used `\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}` to get what you need.

With command `\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}` you get the both addresses aligned (as you mentioned in the comment).

To get justified text simple comment the used command `raggedright` there:

```
% \raggedright% <=======================================================
```

To add the title add the command for the title `\textbf{\@title}` at the right place:

```
% \raggedright% <=======================================================
\textbf{\@title}\\[1.5em]% <==========================================
\@opening\\[1.5em]%
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm} 

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}                             
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}                   
\email{Mail}  


 %Should align both adresses on the same "height", justifing and added title
 \makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
    % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}%
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details%
      \raggedleft%
      \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
        {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
        % optional detailed information
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}\fi%
      \\[1em] % 
      \@date % 
    \end{minipage}\\[2em] 
  % opening
% \raggedright% <=======================================================
  \textbf{\@title}\\[1.5em]% <==========================================
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}
\subsection*{FooFoo}

\clearpage

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\title{Heading should look like this} % <===============================
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus 
et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna 
libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, 
tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci 
lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam 
venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]


\end{document}
```

you get the following wished result:

[image]